# Better paginator for Codeigniter/offset in URI annoys

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I know there is a built in pagination library, but I don't like how the uri segment increments by the offset, e.g.

```
mysite.com/products/10
mysite.com/products/20
```

Is there a better paginator that plays nice with Codeigniter, or is there some way to change the uri segment to show a page number instead of the offset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html):

> `$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;`
>
> By default, the URI segment will use the starting index for the items
>   you are paginating. If you prefer to show the the actual page number,
>   set this to TRUE.

This was added in version 2.1.0. ([changelog](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/changelog.html))

To calculate the offset for your database query, just use `$items_per_page * $page_number`

Answer (score 3):

Enable this in your pagination config:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;
```